# Carousel bootstrap no funciona, no se ejecuta el script (parece)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel, carrusel

Hola muy buenas a toda la comunidad :) estaba haciendo el diseño de una página web usando bootstrap cuando he intentado crear un carousel pero en vez de ejecutarse correctamente me pone las imágenes una encima de otra, en vez de contenidas en la ventana de carousel con el slider funcionando de esta forma:

[image: One on top of each other]

Un dato curioso es que la segunda imagen tiene las flechas prev/next y si pinchas sube un poco la página web (como situando la imagen de forma que sea visible) pero nada más y el indicador de las rayas que te dice qué foto estás visualizando aparece en la tercera imagen. Aquí dejo el código a ver si alguien buenamente pueda ayudarme... muchas gracias! :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Hotel City House Florida Norte</title>

<!-- Bootstrap-->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="HomeHotel.html">Home</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Faranda Rewards</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ofertas</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Habitaciones</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Fotos</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Restaurantes</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Salones</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Opiniones</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mapa</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mi reserva</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Desplegable </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Opcion 1</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Opcion 2</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Opción ultima</a> </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Algo por aqui dani?</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="¿Qué necesitas?" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Búsqueda</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-center"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/logoweb_florida.png" alt="logoweb_florida"> <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h1 class="display-4">Hotel City House</h1>
  <p class="lead">Florida Norte - Madrid</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>¡RESERVE AHORA!</p>
  <p class="lead"> <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a> </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 

      <!-- Indicators -->

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"> <img src="images/Desayuno hotel presentacion.jpg" alt="Desayuno del hotel" width="1010" height="500"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="images/Exteriores nocturno ppio presentacion.jpg" alt="Exteriores con vistas a principe pio en la noche" width="1010" height="500"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="images/Exteriores presentacion.jpg" alt="Exteriores del hotel en el dia" width="1010" height="500"> </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls --> 

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
       </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card"> <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <br>
          <br>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a> <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a> </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br/>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"> Featured </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card"> <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some text to build on the card's content.</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-body"> <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a> <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-4"> Click here to select this<strong> column.</strong> Always place your content within a column. Columns are indicated by a dashed blue line. </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>resize a column</strong> using the handle on the right. Drag it to increase or reduce the number of columns.</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>offset a column</strong> using the handle on the left. Drag it to increase or reduce the offset. </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3>Adding <strong>Buttons</strong></h3>
          <p>Quickly add buttons to your page by using the button component in the insert panel. </p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Info Button</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Success Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3>Adding <strong>Badges</strong></h3>
          <p>Using the insert panel, add badge to your page by using the badge component.</p>
          <span class="badge badge-info">Info Badge</span> <span class="badge badge-danger">Danger Badge</span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
      <h4>Footer </h4>
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2018 &middot; All Rights Reserved &middot; <a href="#" >My Website</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins)-->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed-->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins)  
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> -->

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed 
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap-4.0.0.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el nombre de la clase de los items.

Tu tienes puesto lo siguiente:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"> <img src="images/Desayuno hotel presentacion.jpg" alt="Desayuno del hotel" width="1010" height="500"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="images/Exteriores nocturno ppio presentacion.jpg" alt="Exteriores con vistas a principe pio en la noche" width="1010" height="500"> </div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="images/Exteriores presentacion.jpg" alt="Exteriores del hotel en el dia" width="1010" height="500"> </div>
      </div>
```

Y las clases del carousel-inner tienesn que ser `carousel-item`. Por lo que quedaría así:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active"> <img src="images/Desayuno hotel presentacion.jpg" alt="Desayuno del hotel" width="1010" height="500"> </div>
            <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="images/Exteriores nocturno ppio presentacion.jpg" alt="Exteriores con vistas a principe pio en la noche" width="1010" height="500"> </div>
            <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="images/Exteriores presentacion.jpg" alt="Exteriores del hotel en el dia" width="1010" height="500"> </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Boom! exactamente eso joe muchísimas gracias de verdad me estaba desesperando jaja

Comment: De nada hombre. Pues la verdad es que no... jaja

Answer (score 1):

Por que la libreria Jquery está comentada?, deberías de cargar la lib de jquery.
Y además te está faltando inicializar Carousel.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    })
});
```

Este código deberías agregarlo entre etiquetas `<script>` justo antes de cerrar el `</body>`

Comment: Muchas gracias! :) a ver que soy bastante novato con esto (se de programacion en c, ensamblador y java pero en esto de las paginas web estoy de nuevas) y ese código lo meto entre alguna etiqueta? y donde debería meterlo? como inicializo carousel? joe muchas gracias por tu comentario :)

Comment: Actualizada la respuesta, cualquier error de consola puedes comentarlo por acá y te doy una mano.